# Construct a LINQ query to return an item from a List that is related by one property to other members but which differs by a second property

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a list of objects, let's call them Elephants.

Each elephant object has a property called ClonedFrom. This is of type Elephant and is used to point back at the object that this new object was created in the image of.

The Elephant class also has an other property called HasTrunk which is of type bool.

So:

```
public class Elephant
{
  public Elephant ClonedFrom { get; set; }
  public  bool     HasTrunk { get; set; }
}
```

and we have

```
   List<Elephant> herd
```

I'd like to have a LINQ query that would return any Elephants that have a false HasTrunk property but also have a ClonedFrom property value equal to another Elephant in the same list whose HasTrunk property is set to true.

So for example Elephant A is cloned to create the new elephants B and C

B and C both exist in the herd List and both have the same ClonedFrom property value (A). B has HasTrunk set to false whereas C has hasTrunk set to true.

I'd like a query that returns B.

(note: It's not important that A is or is not in the list)

Comment: `herd.Where(elephant => !elephant.HasTrunk && herd.Where(elephant2 => elephant2.HasTrunk).Contains(elephant2 => elephant2.ClonedFrom == elephant.ClonedFrom));` Is this what you mean ?

Comment: @Ofris that won't compile for me

Comment: What if you change `Contains` to `Any` ?

Comment: @Ofris now it compiles but it doesn't return anything for the test example I outlined above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Elephant> herd = new List<Elephant>{
    new Elephant(), new Elephant(), new Elephant(), new Elephant()
};
herd[0].HasTrunk = true;
herd[1].HasTrunk = true;
herd[2].HasTrunk = false;
herd[3].HasTrunk = false; 
herd[0].ClonedFrom = herd[0];
herd[1].ClonedFrom = new Elephant();
herd[2].ClonedFrom = herd[0];
herd[3].ClonedFrom = new Elephant();
herd.Where(elephant => !elephant.HasTrunk && herd.Where(elephant2 => 
elephant2.HasTrunk).Any(elephant2 => elephant2.ClonedFrom == elephant.ClonedFrom)); //One item - elephant number 2
```